# PHPUnit & Selenium

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phpunit

I have 2 questions:

1. I have a created a lot of testcases in PHPUnit and Selenium but I want to run them as a group rather than 1 at a time.
2. What is the best way to run them on multiple browsers.  I have looked for examples of using webdriver but am unsure how to do it

My 2 testcases are:

#### First:

```
class AdminUserViewReqTabOptions extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase{
  public function setUp()
  {
    $this->setHost('localhost'); // Set the hostname for the connection to the Selenium server.
    $this->setPort(4444); // set port # for connection to selenium server
    $this->setBrowser('firefox'); // set the browser to be used
    $this->setBrowserUrl(''http://www.example.com');  // set base URL for tests
  }

  public function testShowRequestsOnHold()
  {
    $this->url('index.php'); // Set the URL to test
    // check for the existence of the string 'Show requests on hold'
    $this->assertRegExp( '/Show requests on hold/i', $this->source() );        
  }

  public function testShowOnlyPendingApprovals()
  {            
      $this->url('index.php'); // Set the URL to test
      // check for the existence of the string 'Show requests on hold'
      $this->assertRegExp( '/Show only Pending Approvals/i', $this->source() );        
  }
```

}

#### Second:

```
    class AdminUserViewReqTabOptions extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Selenium2TestCase{
       public function setUp()
       {
           $this->setHost('localhost'); // Set the hostname for the connection to the Selenium server.
           $this->setPort(4444); // set port # for connection to selenium server
           $this->setBrowser('firefox'); // set the browser to be used
           $this->setBrowserUrl('http://www.example.com');  // set base URL for tests
       }

       public function testDisplayServer()
             $this->url('index.php'); // Set the URL to test
             // check for the existence of the strin 'All Open'
             $this->assertRegExp( '/Server: Development/i', $this->source() );        
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at

the pull request  https://github.com/giorgiosironi/phpunit-selenium/pull/7

and the sample https://github.com/jlipps/phpunit-selenium/blob/master/Tests/Selenium2TestCase/MultipleBrowsersTest.php

Answer (score 0):

1) If all of your tests are located in the same directory, then try calling phpunit using the directory name instead of a file name. Phpunit will look for *Test.php within the given directory.

2) Remove the setHost(), setPort(), and setBrowser() from your setUp() function and declare your browsers in a static property instead. Below will run each of your tests in each of the declared browsers.

```
public static $browsers = [
    [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 4444,
        'browserName' => 'firefox'
    ],
    [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => 4444,
        'browserName' => 'chrome'
    ]
];
```

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/selenium.html